# automatic session expiration

Tags: php, session

I am facing a strange scenario. basically on my every web page i am doing

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['login']))
    header("Location: login.php");
```

to ensure every user has logged in first. I am working in chrome and what happens is if I login to my web application and open any page it works fine. At the same time if, in another tab, I login to my hosting server, I am logged out of my web application. If I login to my application again, I am logged out of my hosting server!!

What am I doing wrong? is there a problem the way I am checking or setting the session variable?

I am setting the session as follows:

```
//if authentication successful
session_start();
    $_SESSION['login'] = "1";
```

Comment: Set `$_SESSION['login']` to `1`  not `"1"`

Comment: Does your host server use the same domain name as your web application?

Comment: @alex : is there any difference between these two?
George : yes its the same.

Comment: yes one is a string the other is an integer

Comment: Does the host write to the same cookie as your web application, perhaps overwriting the session ID or some other useful piece of information?

Comment: @Alex, in this context, both "1" and 1 will cause `isset($_SESSION['login'])` to return true, so they are functionally equivalent.

Comment: @GeorgeCummins this is true - I just get really annoyed when people use strings to represent integers just because in PHP you can check them just by using `==` and it will cast them... but you're correct in this case it will work just the same.

Comment: two applications on the same domain using the same PHP SESSION

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a very similar problem, and I think this happens just because two sessions with the same name, in the same place of the same domain can't coexist.

Maybe a solution should be to use session cookies. You can set a cookie just for a folder and not for the whole domain. This way I think you can manage 2 sessions at the same time, but I'm not sure.

Try this:

```
session_start();
setcookie(session_name(), session_id(), 0, '/public/');
```

Where `/public/` might be the specific folder where your site is located, or the application path (thanks Paul for pointing out this).

Then you will check if session is set:

```
$session_cookie = 
   isset($_COOKIE[ini_get('session.name')]) ? 
   $_COOKIE[ini_get('session.name')] : 
   null;
```

Probably this won't work, since the other session might be "stored" in the root folder of your web application. But if you are able to do the thing above also for your hosting server, you should resolve your problem.

You can also try to set a different name for the session in your web application.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This answer in essence is GOOD, but insted of a random directory like `/public` you should use your application path, that way your app will be the only one setting a session cookie in that dir. Read: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll find the cause is that both hosts have the same network name e.g. test.www.example.com and www.example.com

Just use a different network name for the test machine and it should work or make sure you explicitly use non-overlapping values for session.cookie_domain